# Prevent overlapping using distribute points on faces node in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to prevent overlapping while I'm using distribute points on faces node, I have no idea

[image: overlapping objects]

Comment: I'm definitely interested in this as well.  To prevent overlap it needs to read in a bit about the geometry of each instance.  I have a similar issue where the geometry being instantiated on each point has random sizes within a range and I'd like to prevent them from overlapping as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option you currently have with `Distribute Points on Faces` is to use the *Poisson Disk* option, and set the *Distance Min* value accordingly.

Here I instantiate circles with a radius of $0.1m$, so I set the *Distance Min* value to $0.2m$.

[image]

Comment: Mine node looks a bit different, I don't have distance min option

Comment: @Eneary You would need to switch the node from *Random* to *Poisson Disk*. Here is the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html

Comment: Didn't see this one, my bad, thanks